# Arquivo php (com html) não está exibindo conteúdo

Tags: php

Estou finalizando um pequeno contador de visitas para um software desktop, e meu problema é que simplesmente o conteúdo deste arquivo.php não está sendo renderizado no navegador, mesmo usando o *Wamp Server*.

Alguém pode me da uma força com isso?

***Conteúdo do arquivo.php***

```
<?php

$user = "AAAAAA";//$_GET['aa'];
$av = "BBBBBBB";//$_GET['bb'];
$so = "CCCCCCCC";//$_GET['cc'];

$plog_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ? $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] : "N/A";
$plog_ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : "N/A";
$plog_host = @gethostbyaddr($plog_ip) ? @gethostbyaddr($plog_ip) : "N/A";
$plog_date = date("d/m/Y"); 
$plog_incr = 1;

if (isset($_GET["view"]))
{
        $linesno = 0;
        if(($flog = @fopen("ntfdll.txt", 'rb')) !== FALSE)
        {
            while (!@feof($flog))
            {
                $shit = @fgets($flog, 4096);
                $linesno++;
            }
            @fclose($flog);
        }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>== / N0T1FY \ == </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.style6 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style11 {color: #990000}
.style20 {color: #990000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.style21 {font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.style22 {font-size: 12px}
.style23 {
    color: #990000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style26 {font-size: 12px; font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-weight: bold; }
.style27 {color: #FFFFFF}
.style28 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-weight: bold; }
.style29 {color: #000000}
.style30 {color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-weight: bold; }
body {
    background-color: #DEDBC6;
}
.style35 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (notify.tif) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="100%" height="68" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="19%" height="48" background="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkmvmnI3Pf1qec8uno1_500.gif">
            <img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkmvmnI3Pf1qec8uno1_500.gif" height="48" alt=""><img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkmvmnI3Pf1qec8uno1_500.gif" width="15" height="48" alt=""></td>
        <td width="81%" background="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkmvmnI3Pf1qec8uno1_500.gif">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td height="17" bgcolor="#DEDBC6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#DEDBC6" class="style23"><div align="right" class="style23"><span class="style35">CLIENTES = <?=($linesno-1) ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr></table>
<div align="right"></div>
<table width="100%" height="69" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr></tr>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="#990000" class="style23">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="right" class="style20"><span class="style27">X</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
    <th width="11%" nowrap bgcolor="#4A4D42" c><div align="center"><span class="style28">DATA</span></div></th>
    <td width="52%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="center" class="style6">
      <div align="left" class="style23">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style27">[IP / Hostname]</span></div>
    </div></td>
    <td width="30%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="left" class="style27">&nbsp;&nbsp;[HTTP Referrer]</div></td>
    <td width="40%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="left" class="style27">&nbsp;&nbsp;[Plugin]</div></td>
    <td width="40%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="left" class="style27">&nbsp;&nbsp;[SO]</div></td>
    <td width="40%" bgcolor="#4A4D42"><div align="left" class="style27">&nbsp;&nbsp;[USER]</div></td>
  </tr>
<?php

        if(($plog_read = @fopen("ntfdll.txt", 'rb')) !== FALSE)
        {

            while (!@feof($plog_read))
            {
                $plog_line = @fgets($plog_read, 4096);
                if(trim($plog_line) != "")
                    echo '<tr><td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C" class="style1"><div align="right" class="style22"><span class="style29">'.$plog_incr++.'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td><td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C"><div align="center" class="style26"><span class="style29">' . $plog_line;
            }
            @fclose($plog_read);

        }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php

    }
else if(isset($_GET["reset"]))
    {
        if(($plog = @fopen("ntfdll.txt", 'wb')) !== FALSE)
        {
            @fputs($plog, '');
            @fclose($plog);
            echo "Lista apagada...";
        }
    }
else if(isset($_GET["v"]))
    {
        $linesno = 0;
        if(($flog = @fopen("ntfdll.txt", 'rb')) !== FALSE)
        {
            while (!@feof($flog))
            {
                $shit = @fgets($flog, 4096);
                $linesno++;
            }
            @fclose($flog);
        }
        echo '<html><body bgcolor="black"><br /><br /><p align="center" style="color:white;font-weight:bold">CLIENTES = '.($linesno > 0 ? $linesno - 1 : 0) .'</p></body></html>';
    }
else
    {
        if(($plog = @fopen("ntfdll.txt", 'ab')) !== FALSE)
        {
            @fputs($plog, '['.$plog_date.']</span></div></td><td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C"><span class="style30">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;['.$plog_ip.', '.$plog_host.']</span></td><td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style29">['.$plog_ref.']</span>                                                                                                                            
            <td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style29">['.$user.']</span></td>
            <td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style29">['.$so.']</span></td>
            <td height="10" bordercolor="#990000" bgcolor="#B5B29C">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style29">['.$av.']</span></td>

            </tr>'."\r\n");
            @fclose($plog);
            echo "OK!";
        }
    }

?>
```

Agradeço por qualquer sugestão aqui deixada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nisso para ver como pode visualizar os erros do script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1817673

Answer (score -1, accepted):

edit: Agora que percebi o restante do código... pelo que deu pra entender no código a página só será exibida se o GET['view'] for setado, ou seja, para acessar a pagina teria que ser

> pagina.php?view=qqercoisa

Caso contrário o conteudo nao aparecerá mesmo.

Comment: em qual linha (parte)? pois existem vários `ifs` :-)

Comment: Tem vários ifs no código. Para que seu comentario não seja negativado, vc poderia adicionar na resposta que if precisa ser fechado.